# How to display date-time in(Minute and Second) only

Tags: javascript, angular, datetime, ionic3

I have an `ion-datetime` form field that has user select minutes and seconds; but, for some reason the form field always shows up blank. I know the answer has to do with the javascript `Date()` function, but I can't seem to get the result I'm wanting.

```
<ion-item class="formField">
      <ion-label stacked>Time</ion-label>
      <ion-label class="warningLabel">(Max of 5 minutes)</ion-label>
      <ion-datetime
          ngModel
          minuteValues="0,1,2,3,4,5"
          displayFormat="mm:ss"
          pickerFormat="mm ss"
          name="selectedTime"
          placeholder=""
          type="date">
      </ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

I've tried using `selectedTime:any = new Date().toISOString();` with `[(ngModel)]="selectedTime"` but it displays the current time already in the form field. The max time I have for the field is 5 minutes so it looks funky. Also, if I need to manipulate the variable and send the value as a separated entity from the form that's perfectly fine, but I was trying to find a way to avoid that. Also, I'm using Angular Template-Driven Forms.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Update: The field breaks because the `displayFormat="mm:ss" pickerFormat="mm ss"` fields aren't recognized by Ionic or the ISO DateTime Format used. So perhaps a work around on this problem would suffice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It displays the current time in the form field because you have instantiated a `Date` with no parameters, therefore, javascript will pick the current date and time. Your code is supposed to be working in spite of the wrong value.

What you can do to sort this out is to instantiate a date with zero milliseconds like `new Date(0)` then you will get zero minutes and zero seconds which make more sense given that you are describing a `timespan`.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  template: `
    <ion-content padding>
      <ion-datetime
        [(ngModel)]="myDate"
        minuteValues="0,1,2,3,4,5"
        displayFormat="mm:ss"
        pickerFormat="mm ss">
      </ion-datetime>
    </ion-content>
  `
})
export class HomePage {
  myDate = new Date(0).toISOString();
}
```